# Rename a set of columns in R by position

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where I want to rename 30 out 45 columns. These 30 columns have different names (they come from different sources), but they are always in position 2:31 in the dataframe. Is there a way to rename columns 2:31 something along the lines of `names(df)[2:31]<- c("name1", "name2", ..., "name30")`? Alternatively, is there a way to use dplyr's `rename` command without giving the names of the columns and instead give their positions?

I know this is sort of basic, but all solutions I could find wanted the opposite, rename a column with a known name at an unknown position.

Comment: Did you try your `names(df)[2:31] <- c("yada", ..., "gah")` way? It works and the answer below is no improvement on it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `colnames()` function

```
X <- data.frame(bad=1:3, worse=1:3)
colnames(X)[1:2] <- c("name1", "name2")
```

You can use `colnames()` and then subset and pass an array with the names. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dplyr `rename`

```
x1 <- data.frame(bad=1:3, worse=1:3)
x2 <- x1 %>% rename(name1 = 1, name2 = 2)
```